# Node.js/Redux/Express error

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, redux

I am teaching myself to use Nodejs with Redux and Express. I have a  tag in my view, and that's it. Very, very basic. I am getting an error in my console that I don't understand:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:548)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at Object.defineProperty.value (bundle.js:492)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:482)
at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
at __webpack_exports__.b (bundle.js:63)
at bundle.js:66
```

Can someone help me figure out what this means?

Here is my server.js file:

```
"use strict"
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express();
var path = require('path'); 

// MIDDLEWARE TO DEFINE FOLDER FOR STATIC FILES
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('app is listening');
})
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
"use strict"

import {createStore} from 'redux'


// STEP 3 define reducers

const reducer = function(state=0, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case "INCREMENT":
        return state + action.payload; 
        break; 
    }
    return state
}


// STEP 1 create the store 
const store = createStore(reducer); 

store.subscribe(function(){
    console.log('current state is: ' + store.getState());
})

// STEP 2 create and dispatch actions
store.dispatch({type: "INCREMENT", payload: 1 })
```

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
var path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/app.js'],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js', 
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
    },
    target: 'node',
    watch: true,
    module: {
       loaders: [
         {
           test: /\.js$/,
           exclude: /node_modules/,
           loader: 'babel-loader',
           query: {
             presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1'] 
           }
         }
       ]
     }
}
```

Comment: how are you running the application?

Comment: node server.js then I use webpack

Comment: This is all extremely new to me. I normally use Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to the plugin portion of your webpack.config

```
   new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production") //or "development"
      }
    });
```

You can read about why this might be your issue below. Basically you need to give webpack a NODE_ENV variable.

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f7850dd3d78d313a9e7774870e85c32719fbe233/docs/docs/getting-started.md